# iPhone App not available in AppStore for iPad (wi-fi only), why? Use of MkMapView maybe?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gps, app-store, wifi

Does using Map Kit framework prevent an app from being available on AppStore for iPad with wi-fi only?

Is it possible that Apple decided the app was meant for outdoors and therefore restricted it to the 3G version of iPad?

Note that this is for an iPhone app (not a Universal or iPad app), and runs on iOS 4.x. Requires Location/GPS.

One of the screens in the app uses MKMapView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some good discussion in the answers/comments posted, but to sum up:

- the iPad Wi-Fi only model does not
  have GPS onboard.
- The app requires GPS (required device
  capability) and is needed for proper
  functioning of the app.
- So Apple was correct to limit the
  sale of the app to devices that have
  GPS (iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS, iPad w/3G)
- Map Kit framework does not require
  GPS to work, so that is unrelated.
- The iPad 3G, confusingly refered to
  by Apple as iPad (Wi-Fi + 3G), has a
  GPS chip: Broadcom BCM4750UBG
  Single-Chip AGPS Solution. It can be
  seen here:
  http://jetlib.com/news/tag/chip-agps/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the root cause is, but I had a similar experience. I released Circle 8 for iPhone back in September (before iOS 4.2 came out for iPad) and it required iOS 4.0+ in order to use MapKit.  Searching the App Store for Circle 8 from an iPad did not show Circle 8, even under "iPhone apps."  After I installed iOS 4.2 on my iPad, searching the App Store from my iPad *still* did not show Circle 8.  It was only once I released a universal binary of Circle 8 that it began to appear in an App Store search from the iPad.  Weird, huh?

Comment: Right, but I'm not even talking about searches, I'm saying that when you view the app details in iTunes it says "Requirements: Compatible with iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4 and iPad Wi-Fi+3G. Requires iOS 4.0 or later". Also, someone I know tried to buy it on their iPad and they got a message like "This app is not compatible with your iPad"

Comment: I've seen that sort of message when someone tries to install the app onto an iPad running iOS 3.2.  It does seem a little weird that it doesn't list iPod touch under "Compatible with..."

Answer (score 0):

It's because your app "Requires Location/GPS." For iOS devices, Location/GPS requires cellular hardware.

As shown in the [Tech Specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), Wi-Fi + 3G model adds these Location abilities:

- Assisted GPS
- Cellular

[Assisted GPS uses the cellular network.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

> Some aGPS devices do not have the
>   option of falling back to standalone
>   or autonomous GPS.

Comment: Um, Location/GPS requires GPS. Not sure why it would require cellular hardware. Can you point to any docs on this?

Comment: I think the key point here is that iPad (wi-fi only) does not have GPS chips/capability. And here I was thinking that when Apple put "Assisted GPS (Wi-Fi + 3G model)" on the iPad specs it meant that Assisted GPS was available on both the Wi-Fi and the 3G model, when instead it looks like they mean its available only on the iPad that has 3G capability. So its not really that Location/GPS requires "celluar hardware" its just that they didn't put GPS hardware into the wi-fi only iPad.

Comment: @Paul this is exactly right: in the iPad (and in the iPhone vs. the iPod Touch), the GPS is part of the cellular chip. Understand though, that the WiFi iPad can use MapKit and Core Location just fine, as long as it has a WiFi connection.

Comment: @Matthew/@Jon: Well its sort of a moot point as far as this questions concerned, but the iPad 3G model uses the Broadcom BCM4750UBG Single-Chip AGPS Solution, which is a separate chip and not part of the cellular hardware (per my understanding and you can see it here: http://jetlib.com/news/tag/chip-agps/). But the model of iPad that includes this chip happens to also be the one with celluar 3G hardware. Also I would suspect, but haven't tried it, that the iPad GPS chip will work fine even with no cell signal, but time to initial fix may be longer.